# Batch script to build ruby gems

Tags: ruby, batch-file, rubygems

I have the following directory structure.

```
build
  -build.bat
package
  -gems
    -abc.gem
    -xyz.gem
  -install.sh
plugins
  -abc
    -abc.gemspec
  -xyz
    -xyz.gemspec
```

I am trying to write the batch file build.bat in build folder.
The tasks it should perform are :

1. Delete any previous files in package/gems folder
2. Inside each subdirectory of plugins folder, execute

   `gem build *.gemspec`

   This command will create a gem file in the same directory.
3. Move the gem file created to package/gems folder

I have been going through batch programming syntax, and i am not even sure whether this can be achieved by batch script or not. How can I write a batch script that will do these tasks?

[Edit]

After some basic research I was able to accomplish a lot of the tasks.

```
@echo on

cd..
set CUR_DIR=%cd%
set GEMS_DIR=%CUR_DIR%\Package\gems
set PLUGINS_DIR=%CUR_DIR%\Plugins

del /f/s/q/a %GEMS_DIR%\

cd %PLUGINS_DIR%

for /d %%D in (*) do (
    pushd %%~fD 
    gem build *.gemspec
    move *.gem %GEMS_DIR%
    popd
)
```

However, the move command copies both .gem and .gemspec files. How do i restrict it to only move the .gem files? Also, any lines added after the last parenthesis do not execute.
Any other improvements will be appreciated. Thank you.

[Edit2]

Any lines i added after the foor loop were not being executed. After adding `call` infront of the gem command, everything works fine.

Comment: It's very probable that this can be done - and quite easily. However, this site is not a free code-writing service. Please edit your attempt at solving the problem into your post using the `edit` facility and then we may attempt to hone it to an operational condition if you run into any problems.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for the motivation to do my own research in batch scripting. Loved this line in your profile - 'I don't mind solving even dumb and obvious problems. Keeps whats left of my grey-matter from solidifying.'

Comment: Lines after the last parenthesis? As Nelson may have said "I see no lines..."

Answer (score 1):

replace the

```
move *.gem %GEMS_DIR%
```

with

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.gem* ^|findstr /E /L /I ".gem" 2^>nul') do move "%%a" "%gems_dir%"
```

noting:

The `%%a` in the `for` statement can be any alphabetic (other than `D` which is used for the outer loop) and *IS* case-sensitive, whereas batch is otherwise case-insensitive as far as instructions and variables are concerned.

This generates a `/b` (basic) `dir` listing (ie. names only) `/a-d` without directorynames, of files matching `*.gem*`. This will naturally select `*.gem` and `*.gemspec` files (which are being picked up by the `move *.gem` because they have a short-name of *something with~n.gem* (see a `dir /x` listing).

Having generated the listing (in memory), pipe that list to `findstr` to find all lines (ie. filenames) which `/E` end `/L` with the literal `/I` case-Insensitive ".gem". The `^` escapes the redirector characters to tell `cmd` that the redirector is part of the *single-quoted command-to-executed* not of the `for`. The `2>nul` redirects any unwanted "not found" output from the `findstr` to *nowhere* should any appear (redirecting 2=stderr).

The `for`assigns the entirety of any line (=filename which *may* contain spaces) to `%%a` since `"delims="` means "no delimiters"

Hence, `%%a` should contain only the names of the file(s) which end specifically `.gem`.

And quoting is simply good policy - it essentially escapes the standard operation of separators like <kbd>Space</kbd> and removes their special meaning.